# Statistical significance of co-efficient derived through several regressions for panel data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, least-squares, panel-data, cross-section

For the panel data that I have, I'm trying to run multiple one-variable regressions (y=ax+e) across time periods - i.e. one for each time period.
Naturally, the a's that I find from each regression that I run - form a distribution.

1) Can I estimate the overall 'a' for this data-set as the mean of all the a's that I find, or would I have to weight the regressions based on the inverse of the individual standard errors of the a estimates to get an appropriate estimate? (Because the low standard deviation estimates of a have a greater amount of 'information' in them?)

2) How can I understand if the estimate is statistically different from zero? Would I be correct in simply running a t-test on the t-stat = mean of all a's/std. deviation of a's? And what would I do if I follow the second approach?
Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you are striving to do (and also not why), but Swamy's random coefficient model might be what you are looking for (Swamy, P.A.V.B. (1970). Efficient Inference in a Random Coefficient Regression Model, Econometrica, 38(2), pp. 311–323).

Comment: @Helix123 Thank you! I'll take a look. :)